# How to Signup a ParseUser in Local Unit Test

Tags: android, parse-platform, robolectric, back4app

In Local unit test, does VM allow to hit online through ParseUser, and Signup?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to user Signup the user, you can use the code below:

```js
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
// Set the user's username and password, which can be obtained by a forms
user.setUsername(<Insert Username Here>);
user.setPassword(<Insert User Password Here>);
user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
 @Override
 public void done(ParseException e) {
     if (e == null) {
         alertDisplayer("Sucessful Sign Up!","Welcome" + <Insert Username Here> + "!");
     } else {
         ParseUser.logOut();
         Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
 }
});
```

If you need more information, at Back4App site have Docs about it and a template too :)